# Copy files recursively from a hierarchy to a single flat folder

Tags: powershell, copy

Is it possible to copy all the files contained recursively from a specific folder and its subfolders directly to a only one flat directory without respecting anymore the source hierarchy folders?

Comment: I mean contained and not contains, sorry for this error.

Comment: You can edit your original post to correct it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course that's possible. Why not?

```
Counter = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path <Path> -Filter * -Recurse -File |
    Copy-Item -Destination <Destination Path> -PassThru |
        Foreach-Object{
            $counter++
            Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName ($_.BaseName + '_' + ("{0:000}" -f $Counter) + $_.Extension)
        }
```

Comment: Thank you Olaf. Would it be possible to change the name of each copied file to an increasing counter (avoid duplicated name), please?

Comment: @pindare most things are possible in PowerShell ... with a bit of effort.

Answer (score 0):

Based on Olaf's answer:

```
$Counter = 0
Get-ChildItem -Path "./Path" -Filter * -Recurse -File |
    Foreach-Object {
        $Counter++
        Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination "./Destination/$($_.BaseName + '_' + ("{0:000}" -f $Counter) + $_.Extension)"
    }
```