# powershell copy and change the name of each copied file by an increasing counter

Tags: powershell

Would it be possible in Powershell to change the name of each copied file to an increasing counter by keeping the same file extension, for example:
The first selected source file: fileA.txt would become: file_001.txt,
The second file: fileB.doc would become: file_002.doc,
The third would become: file_003.txt and so on...

Comment: Yes it is possible, you can use `Rename-Item` to rename every file and then, make a `for` loop that counts up the numbers after the name

Comment: You're too impatient. See my original answer to your original question

Comment: Here's the complete anser [Copy files recursively from a hierarchy to a single flat folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49852380/copy-files-recursively-from-a-hierarchy-to-a-single-flat-folder/49852496#49852496)

Comment: @Olaf it’s more likely their boss is impatient for the script ‘they’ are writing ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Check out this function and see if it works.

```
function Copy-EnumerateFiles {
    param(
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        $Source,
        [ValidateScript({Test-Path $_})]
        $Destination        
    )
    [int]$i = 1
    $Files = Gci -Path $Source    
        Foreach($File in $Files) {            
            Copy-item -Path "$($file.fullname)" -Destination $Destination
            Rename-Item -Path $Destination\$($file.Name) -NewName "$($file.BaseName)_$($i)$($file.Extension)"
            $i++           
        }
}
```